# strange behavior of enable_if

Tags: c++, c++14, enable-if

does anyone know why the following code compiles

```
static const size_t CONSTANT = /* ... */;

template< size_t M = CONSTANT, typename std::enable_if_t< M!=1, size_t > = 0 >
res_type</*...*/> foo()
{
  // ...
}
```

while this does not:

```
static const size_t CONSTANT = /* ... */;

template< typename std::enable_if_t< CONSTANT!=1, size_t > = 0 >
res_type</*...*/> foo()
{
  // ...
}
```

Many thanks in advance.

Best

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SFINAE requires the failed substitution to be dependant on a template parameter.

If the substitution failure happens at the first phase of the lookup (in other words, when it is not dependant on template parameters) the program is ill-formed, no diagnostics required. But the popular compilers yield a readable error in this case.

Otherwise the compiler must wait for the instantiation of the template specialization to know whether substitution can take place. If it cannot, it is required by the language not to produce a hard error, but be silently ignored instead.

Comment: @KerrekSB Indeed. Rephrased. Is it better now?

Comment: It's still a bit tentative. Why "can" -- it sounds like you're not sure and hedging your bets :-) And what is "it"?

Comment: (The interesting distinction that you may be looking for is between "first and second phase", i.e. template definition vs instantiation of a template specialization.)

Comment: @KerrekSB sorry to ping you again, but... How about now?

Comment: @KerrekSB Technically speaking, this is ill-formed NDR (see [\[temp.res\]/8](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/temp.res#8)). It's not required to produce a hard error, or a substitution failure; the behavior of the entire program is undefined.

Comment: @T.C. Would it also be ill-formed if the non-dependant expression appeared in a partial specialization?

Comment: Yes. A partial specialization is itself a template, so same rules apply.

Comment: @T.C. I rephrased it. I hope it is closer to correct now.